# SUM of multiple INDEX+MATCH entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Sorry if this is a duplicated question.
I have several spreadsheets with plenty of source data,
In which I usually use INDEX+MATCH to find out the source data for the corresponding value,
As shown in the graph here, this is just an example.

Graph:
[image: Example sheet]

Example sheet here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yixftcr83tkoid2/example_sheet.xlsx?dl=0

Usually I need to see only some selected user's data on a specific month, it can be done by INDEX+MATCH(or vlookup), but now I want to add a sum for these selected user data on specific month. In the real sheet I have a lot of selected users and also lots of different month that I want to compare of, so I want to avoid doing the J10 SUM again and again. Is there any way I can do this?
(Basically to a single task that finds the index value for user listed in I7-I9 and then sum up...)

P.S my actual list for index/match is more than 5,000 rows so I use like X:X for match.

Comment: Sorry I may miss a point here: In my many sheets I need to create similar summ for different I7:I9 lists. Sometimes it is I7:I12, sometimes I7:I8...so the list itself is not fixed(Sometimes can be VERY long...).And in real sheets there might only be the I7:IXXX table, however I want to find the SUM with different list selected. So, with the same array formula in J10, I can choose a range of list and generate the SUM, instead of using SUM(INDEX(I7)+INDEX*I8)+INDEX(I9)...) thanks!

Comment: Basically I want to do like this:
J10=SUM(IFERROR((INDEX($B$4:$G$12, (MATCH({I7:I9}, $A$4:$A$12,0)),5)),"0"))
However I can't find a way to do the multiple match in I7:I9 as an array...

Answer (score 0):

If you have some cells where you write the Users which you need to Sum and the 
month, for example:

```
I6    May
I7    User1
I8    User3
I9    User7
I10   Sum
```

In J10 you can write the following:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(I6),A:A,I7)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT(I6),A:A,I8)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT(I6),A:A,I9)
```

But first Define Name for each month for one time only:

- Formulas
- Define Name
- Write Jan in Name Box
- In Refers to write =Sheet!$B:$B

Repeat the same for each month and change the column references:

- Feb  =Sheet!$C:$C
- Mar  =Sheet!$D:$D
- Apr  =Sheet!$E:$E
- May  =Sheet!$F:$F
- Jun  =Sheet!$G:$G

Now whenever you change I6 to a different month it will recalculate for the new month automatically.
Whenever you change the users in I7-I9 the formula will recalculate automatically.
Indirect will evaluate the value in I6 to the corresponding column with the same range name

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the month name you require on a cell, as appeared on your source table. Example: `May` on `I3` (change `I3` to a more appropriate cell)
2. Change the 3rd parameter on your `INDEX` to this `MATCH($I$3, $B$3:$G$3, 0)`

Basically it look up the name of the month specified on `I3` from the table header (`B3:G3`) and return the column number. It should look like this:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$G$12, MATCH(I7, $A$4:$A$12, 0), MATCH($I$3, $B$3:$G$3, 0))
```

You can then proceed to `SUM` the result.